# gdb: printing a variable not in the current scope

Tags: scope, gdb, local-variables, callstack

I am using gdb and I was wanting to print a variable not currently in the scope.  I am not sure what the exact name of the variable is so I would like to be able to change scopes rather than printing a specific variable in a specific file.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `frame`, `up` and `down` commands to access scopes on the stack.

```
frame N
f N
    Select frame number N. (The current instruction is in frame 0.)

up [N]
    Move N frames up the stack (away from frame 0).

down [N]
    Move N frames down the stack (towards frame 0).
```

Comment: Does `frame` means `scope` though? Say, does `frame up` mean `outer least scope`? Or `gdb` only scores breakpoint jumps as frames?

Comment: @Multifix They mean call frames. In C and C++, there's a 1-to-1 correspondence; I'm unfamiliar with debugging other compiled languages.